# Overcoming The Boolean Input Tests in the Codewars Kata: "Master your primes: sieve with memoization" - Ruby

Tags: ruby, primes, memoization, boolean-expression, sieve

I'm currently doing the 5kyu "Master your primes: sieve with memoization" kata on Codewars. The challenge
gives you a cached array of the first 4 prime numbers, and you must check if n (e.g. 5) is a prime in that array, if so, return true. If necessary (e.g. if n = 143), you must add primes to the cached array and stop when you get to n, then check if n is in the array (and hence a prime a number).

My code (below) is passing the tests for checking if prime or not. The problem is they've thrown in some strange inputs:

n = ($primes.size-5).abs<3 (test expects true)

n = ($primes.size-9).abs<3 (test expects true)

My code is currently only failing these 2 inputs. When I've evaluated them based on the where the cached array will be at that time, they both evaluate to false. The first line in my method attempts to return
true if the value of n is false, I've tried this in 2 other ways also, nothing works so far.

Frustratingly, there's no mention whatsoever of these surprise tests in the kata description. As far as I'm aware the inputs ask "is the absolute value of the length of $primes minus 5 (and later 9), less than 3?"

Someone please explain to me if I'm wrong, what those inputs mean and how I can improve my code to pass these tests (and the kata).

```
require "prime"

$primes = [2,3,5,7]

def is_prime(n)
  return true if n.class == FalseClass
  return true if n <= $primes.max && $primes.include?(n)
  ($primes.max+1..n).each do |p|
    next if !p.prime?
    $primes << p
  end
  $primes.include?(n) ? true : false
end
```

Comment: Looking at the discussion for that kata, there are lots of similar complaints. It seems the kata is simply poorly written.

Comment: It's definitely poorly written, but people have completed it though.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to solve this kata without using the `prime` gem. If you do the prime test yourself you will see why the tests make sense.

The tests from that Kata, in order, are

```
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(1),false)
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(2),true)
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(5),true)
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(143),false)
Test.assert_equals(($primes.size-5).abs<3,true)
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(-1),false)
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(29),true)
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(53),true)
Test.assert_equals(is_prime(529),false)
Test.assert_equals(($primes.size-9).abs<3,true)
```

Testing 1, 2, and 5 can be done without modifying the memo, but 143 is the first number where the prime test could involve adding more primes to the memo. 143 = 11x13 so an absolutely minimal memo would only include [2,3,5,7,11] at this point. I believe that the kata is trying to verify that you aren't adding unnecessary primes to the memo. For some reason they added some wiggle room so you can have two extra primes in the memo and it will still pass.

The next tests are a little more advanced. 29 is prime, but again we don't have to add anything to the memo to detect that. As we go through the memo of known primes, we'll check if it is divisible by 2, 5, and... we're done actually. 5x5=25 which is less than 29 but 7x7=49 which is **greater** than 29. That means if 29 was divisible by 7 or some larger prime, it would also be divisible by a smaller prime than 7. But we've already checked all smaller primes and it *isn't* divisible. Therefore 29 is prime.

The same technique works for 53 because we already have 11 in the memo and 11x11>53.

The last check for 529 is similar to the one before. 529=23x23 so we have to get up to 23, which is the 9th prime.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow!

Comment: Okay, so what I'm not understanding about your solution is what system are you using to check if the input is prime or not? (E.g. where does 11 x 13 come into this?)

Second, under what condition do we add a prime number to the memo?

I'm able to pass the basic tests now but they're failing the length checks after large numbers. I add very few primes, it says.expected 17000, got 16. I add up to sqrt of each n (uniq), it says expected 9, got 22000.

As an aside, I've learned Sieve of Eratosthenes today and I have no clue how it's supposed to be used in this kata, if it has to at all.

Comment: I think you are expected to use a slightly different kind of sieve. If you have a list of all primes <= sqrt(n), then n is prime if and only if it is not divisible by any of those primes. To be absolutely minimal, you only want to expand the list of primes after you checked all of them. E.g. we don't have to add primes up to 1,000 to check if 1,000,000 is prime because it is divisible by 2, which is in our memo.